# Cannot display DataFrame in Pycharm?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pycharm

in Pycharm i got this code:

```
import pandas as pd
years = range(2014, 2018)
shop1 = pd.Series([2409.14, 2941.01, 3496.83, 3119.55], index=years)
shop2 = pd.Series([1203.45, 3441.62, 3007.83, 3619.53], index=years)
shop3 = pd.Series([3412.12, 3491.16, 3457.19, 1963.10], index=years)

a = pd.concat([shop1, shop2, shop3])

print(a)
```

So, i am able to look at my code in the console, but i wanna display it like if you just call `a` in Jupyter. I tried this uttorial, but it is not working at all: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/viewing-as-array.html

Comment: What exactly is not workling. Its works for me in pycharm. Are you using the Python console or the run terminal?

Comment: I use Python console. When i click on the Debugger, there are no variables shown up.

Comment: What is shown in your Variable View ?

Comment: "Variables are not avalable"

Comment: Did you select a valid Python interpreter?

Comment: Oh, you have to double click the line to make a red circle appear on the left of the line.

Comment: That's a breakpoint for your debugger.

Comment: ok, can you maybe tell me where to put the breakpoint? In which line to display the dataframe?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201209/discussion-between-luigigi-and-derick-kolln).